# iphone Japanese Keyboard

Tags: iphone, internationalization, keyboard

Is there a way to check if the iphone keyboard is currently in Japanese vs English input mode?

I would just check the Unicode characters but the numpad on the Japanese keyboard sends regular ASCII characters I think...

Comment: I would personally avoid trying to determine which keyboard is being used and deal with invalid input programatically, since the user might paste invalid text into the field and at that point, it doesn't matter what keyboard is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not way to check what keyboard is being displayed, the best you can do is either display a alert to user telling him he must use japanesee keyboard or make your own keyboard and push that in there.

Answer (score 2):

If you dive into the private API you can determine the currently active input manager:

```
NSLog(@"Active Input Manager: %@", [[objc_getClass("UIKeyboardInputManager") activeInstance] class]);
```

Comment: Thanks :), that's pretty cool. I think I'm going to stay away from private API stuff for my application though, for fear of rejection. Out of curiosity, is there documentation for the private API?

Comment: In general, Apple can't detect most private API calls (including the one above); as long as your app fails gracefully it should be fine.

There's no documentation for most of the private API, but you can generate the headers using class-dump: http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z